# 13.10 installation interrupted

Tags: installation, updates, 13.10

I used the GUI to update from 13.04, and left it overnight. I came back to a frozen screen with a prompt to replace a repository. I hard-restarted, and now when I start up, I get a prompt, "System program problem detected" before the desktop even starts up, and the computer is barely responsive.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you hard-restarted, you've likely caused your OS to go into a completely unstable setup.  The easiest fix for this would be to do a clean install from a boot disk or thumb drive.  Even better, if you have access to another computer and can burn a 13.10 image, then do a clean install with the version you're trying to update.  Hopefully you had everything backed up before you started the upgrade.